# How to remove a search filter after an error is generated?

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, filter

I have a bit of an annoying problem.  I setup a search filter in the Product Catalog window filtering for a specific website.

Later in the day, after some testing, I deleted that website/store/storeview.

Now, when I go back to the Product Catalog table, it generates a "Something went wrong" error, which then prevents me from ever clearing the problematic filter.

Does anybody know of a way to remove a filter after an error has been generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short-term solution is actually stated in the above linked github issue:

"When you get the "Something went wrong" message, open Developer Tools console in your browser and type there:

```
jQuery('.action-clear').click();
```

That will simulate the "Clear All" link click for filters (tried in Chrome). Hope it will help."

Answer (score 0):

This grid is created wiht the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid` class. If you look inside the `_construct()` method, you will find this code:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('productGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setVarNameFilter('product_filter');
}
```

Notice the `setSaveParametersInSession(true)` call? This is how Magento saves the filters in the session. If you logout, the session should be closed and you should have a fresh grid.

In the future, if you want to remove session-filter saving, you can replace the class, or otherwise modify the block, like with a plugin.

Comment: I actually dumped all of /var/sessions, cleared all caches, logged in with a freshly empty firefox(I only use it to do tests like this), making sure all cookies and local cache was empty, and somehow the filter remained.
That's the only reason I even asked this question. I then took the stance that it was poor error handling in M2's part, and opened a ticket for this problem.

[link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8538)

Comment: And sorry, I should say thank you for that information though, I hope to not need to use it, but it will help where to look if I need too again.